# Angular HttpClient not sending the properties provided by a gettter

Tags: angular, typescript

student.ts

```
...

private _status: string;

...

get status() {
  return this._status;
}

...
```

---

student.service.ts

```
...

save(student: Student): Observable<Student> {
  const postStudentURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/students';
  return this.httpClient.post<Student>(postStudentURL, student);
}

...
```

---

JSON sent to back-end

```
{
...

"_status": "Valid",

...
}
```

---

**Why status is not sent and instead the private _status is sent ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return this.httpClient.post<Student>(postStudentURL, student);
```

The line above sends `json` representation of student object.

so the request contains field instead of getter.

For confirmation you can manually create a instance of `Student` and then `console.log(JSON.stringify(student))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just expected the json to include the value returned from getter as a property, as it does represent a property

Comment: JSON doesn't ignore accessors. Full stop. JSON only considers "own" properties and class accessors are placed on the prototype not on `this`.

Comment: I appreciate that you edited this, but now it does not make sense.